# Are Centos directory server and 389 directory server the same?

Tags: centos, 389-ds

I have very broad view that Redhat Directory server , 389 directory server and Centos Directory server are all the same. Its just the support you pay for on the RedHat version.

Is this true ?  Are there any differences between centos ds and 389 ds ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CentOS Directory Server is a rebuild of the Red Hat Directory server & 389-ds is LDAP server developed in the Fedora project.

CentOS use source package provided by Red Hat to build its own bits after little modification (logos,name)